# Salt and password

Tags: passwords, salt

Reading the doc for setting the password, the command is : python -c "import crypt; print crypt.crypt('password', '\$6\$SALTsalt')"

SALTsalt is the 8-character crpytographic salt. Valid characters in the salt are ., /, and any alphanumeric character.

So, do I type in different password, and replace SALTsalt?
Can someone give an example of this?

Comment: reading which doc to set which password ?

Answer (score 1):

The salt doesn't need to be 8 chars long. It can be longer, and my version of python will truncate it at 16 bytes.

To store passwords using crypt, create a random salt for every user, and store the result.

One example:

```
python -c "import crypt; print crypt.crypt('password', '\$6\$123456789012345678901234567890')"
$6$1234567890123456$YfUD.j5zIFtfV6VgikPof2dzCCCZwL2YDraBX4HXi.J7iNq24667epYUCZGxExqOmHTnPWybzfYaynT29vKXJ/

python -c "import crypt; print crypt.crypt('insecure', '\$6\$12CsGd8FRcMSMV6VgikPof2dzCC0')"
$6$12CsGd8FRcMSMV6V$kSCxbE5y6ihnYHJ4UmbqUm6ohnhAmUYKaZQOpLQuXVXXzJuz4deR7pueK8vSx0f0OqtyhI9i0nd/Devv5bPT31
```

In the last example, it will show the salt (`$6$12CsGd8FRcMSMV6V`), and the hashed password (`kSCxbE5y6ihnYHJ4UmbqUm6ohnhAmUYKaZQOpLQuXVXXzJuz4deR7pueK8vSx0f0OqtyhI9i0nd/Devv5bPT31`). To check the password later, you must hash it again with the same salt (you will need to save the salt in the database) and compare to the value stored on the database.

Comment: Yeesh. That's a terrible password-hashing API. Forcing you to provide a formatted crypt-version and salt? Madness.

Comment: Not that terrible. It works quite well and it's secure enough for most places. And the salt and password are only variables, so does not matter how complex the command are.

Comment: Not only does it practically forces you to use string interpolation, but it also encourages the developer to personally deal with salts. Why not recommend the simpler version demonstrated in the docs? `crypt.crypt('password', crypt.METHOD_SHA512)` to generate the hash and `hash == crypt.crypt('password', hash)` to verify it?

Comment: How did you use longer than 2 character Salts? When I use 'aa' or 'aabbbbbbbbbb' as salts, it outputs same thing.

Comment: You way is surely easier. But without proper salting, the vast majority of your passwords will be leaked by only one SQL injection. Using a long random salt will increase the security by a wide margin.

Comment: @okk I tried here and got different results. Using your `aa` and `aabbbbbbbbbb` as salts gave vastly different hashes, as expected.

Comment: @ThoriumBR It seems like mine only supports 8 characters of password and 2 characters of salt. Do you happen to know why this is? I am using basic terminal.

Comment: For instance, when I try python -c "import crypt; print crypt.crypt('password','\$6\$123456789012345678901234567890')"     I get, 6FMi11BJFsAc.

Comment: My python is `Python 2.7.6`. Your may be different.

Comment: Actually, my password is truncated at 8 characters and my salt is truncated at 2 characters. Why is this happening?

Comment: @okk You have to use a salt in the correct format. If you don't use the proper format `crypt` will revert to backward compatibility with the old and insecure `DES` based format.

Comment: @kasperd I am using the correct format. It seems like my password is limited to 8 characters while salt is limited to 2. I have no idea why this is.

Comment: @okk You are using the `DES` based format, which is limited to 2 character salt and 8 character password. And since you haven't specified what software you are using, there is no way we can tell you any more than that.

Comment: @kasperd I am using putting in same line and word by word that ThoriumBR used. I am just typing it into my command prompt on my macbook. If you see my other post, it can show you what I typed in.